# TextView gets cut off at the end of the screen

Tags: android, textview

I'm having a problem with the TextView in my App.
so far it works normally on 3 phones that I've tested it on, but unfortunately it tends to behave strangely on a phone running the MIUI ROM.

the String gets cut off at the end of the screen, instead of just doing a linebreak:
[image]

it's just a regular TextView...this is the XML code by the way:

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/question_text"
                android:text="@string/question"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                >
```

any guesses, why it gets cut off in the particular ROM?

Comment: Any luck in finding the problem. Same issue here

Comment: it's too long ago, I don't even remember how I got it to work lol.......

Have you tried "singleline="false"?

Comment: Yes its worked. But i found some other solution also. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: could you share your 'other solution' ? maybe I'll help the next guy ;)

Comment: May sound idiotic but I opened the graphical view of the layout and fixed it by simple stretching the text view. Seems like it was hiding or was not able to stretch its height when increased from the xml. Now wrap_content works fine. All i need to do is just recheck it from the graphical view.

Comment: :) did it change any code in the XML-file?

Comment: No change from the XML!!!! Strange yet true

Comment: I second @FahadIshaque. Using the xml viewer may help. In my case - I had an "alignParentRight" property, which was cleared by the graphical palette and fixed my issue (doing an undo in the xml perspective after the change - you can detect the change in the code).

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

in your textview

Comment: that would only allow the string to break into multiple lines, I think the OP wants in one line

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason for the issue is the ROM uses a different font or the phone has a display of smaller size, which causes your string to be wider than the string.

You can use the `ellipsize` parameter to avoid the text getting "broken". [Here is the documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) Based on the the setting - your textview may have the "..." signs in the beginning, middle, end, have no signs and be cut off at the end, or animate horizontally (marquee).